# In my DiD regression, I have % change as dependent variable and log(x) as a regressor. How do I interpret the beta coefficient?

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients, spatial, difference-in-difference

I am trying to study how rent changes has evolved over distance to the city center between the pre- and post-COVID time periods. So I devote particular focus on comparing the relative rental and house price developments in city centers vs. suburban areas. Here is my regression equation:
[image]

i indexes postcodes, c indexes counties and m indexes city regions. %Δ Rent denotes the change of median rent in postcode i, between the time period YE-2019 and year t. log(1+Dist_Center) is log (one plus the Euclidean distance between the centroid of postcode i and the centroid of the closest city centre’s postcode).

**How do I interpret beta 1 here?**
For eg. if i get beta 1 to be 0.1. Would it mean that a 1% increase in distance raises rent by 0.001%?
Any clarifications or opinions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you first add one before taking the logarithm? // I don't see the characteristic interaction term of a DiD in your regression, but that is a separate issue.